Autocorrelation function of conditional expectation.
I am working on a problem involving stochastic processes and would appreciate some help and guidance.
Given:

$X(t)$ is a zero-mean wide-sense stationary Gaussian process with an autocorrelation function $R(\tau) = \exp(-|\tau|)$.
$Y(t) = X(t) - 2X(t - 1)$.

Let:

$Z(t) = \mathbb E[X(0) + (Y(0))^2 | Y(t)]$.

I would like to calculate the autocorrelation function of the stochastic process $Z(t)$.
Here is what I have considered so far:

I understand that $Z(t)$ is the conditional expectation based on $Y(t)$, so the relationship between $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ needs to be taken into account.
I know I need to use the autocorrelation function $R(\tau)$ in the calculation.

Specifically, I am unsure how to handle the conditional expectation part and how to transition from $Y(t)$ to the autocorrelation function of $Z(t)$.
I would greatly appreciate any insights and solutions you can provide.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.
